# DevExteme Cancel button stays on navigating away from component

Tags: angular, devextreme

I am having a very weird problem, using a the DevExtreme library I have built a cell editable datagrid and implemented validation on it. On an error for a particular field a red Revert Button appears. The same Revert button  does not go away when user navigates to another page particularly using routing. However, when you navigate to another component which is dynamically generated it is can be removed using cancelEditData() funtion exposed by DevExtreme's datagrid instance. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/99m4ktMu7VUv2uUQObcE?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem, try the below steps to replicate the issue.

- Clear up the value for the Column Name field in the first row and click outside which would give you the red revert button
- Now, click on the top lavel "My Component" menu item and you would see that the button stays on that screen
- But, when you do that by clicking in the Child 2 side bar menu link it disappears as both Child 1 and Child 2 are generated dynamically and not via routing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I already contacted DevExtreme support and they are saying this is a problem with the Angular 2 framework, but why that beats me.

**Code of interest is on src/parent.ts**

```
onItemClick( event ) {
    // this works as this is invoked before I create the new component   
    if (this.currentComponentHolder.instance.gridInstance)
      this.currentComponentHolder.instance.gridInstance.cancelEditData();

    let item = event.itemData;
    this.setContent( item.component );
}

// this is the piece which is not working. Also, noteworthy is the fact that the above working code also does not work when i put it in the ngOnDestroy of Child1 component.
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.currentComponentHolder.instance.gridInstance)
        this.currentComponentHolder.instance.gridInstance.cancelEditData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run the Plunker, getting tons of console error messages

However, looking at parent.ts, I see that you have no `implement OnDestroy` here:

```
export class Parent implements OnInit
```

You need to also import OnDestroy. Try that and let me know!

Comment: That is indeed surprising as the plunker just works fine for me, can you check what kind of errors are you getting? 
Yes, I did try OnDestroy in my app and it did not matter as you can see onNgDestroy method is already there in parent.ts. I did debug using developer console and could see the method getting executed.

Comment: I was able to run the Plunkr this time around. I think your issue ia devextreme one rather than an angular one. The call cancelEditData() is not really doing anything.

I think for cancelEditData(), the cell has to be in focus mode. I have not used devExtreme before so I wasn't able to figure it out on timely manner. Good luck

Comment: thanks that makes sense, and after a few back and forth DevExtreme did agree that it is there issue and are fixing it.

Comment: glad to hear that